# Finding a set open or closed?

Tags: calculus

How can I find the interior points, boundary, and whether the following set is open or closed.

and make a graph. 
The set is

all real numbers

$\frac{x-5}{x+10}\le=0$

Well one of the boundaries is 0 and it is included in the set. But it seem to be the only boundary it the set.

It seem to keep going in the negative real numbers.

The interior point would be all real numbers except negative -10 all the way up to zero.

So would the interior point be.

$[-\infty,-10)U[\infty,0)$

the boundary is the point $(0,-1/2)$

but I am not sure how a graph would look like?

Comment: Try solving the inequality. The interior points you have listed are not correct.

Comment: Hmm solving the inequality I get x<=5 so that could be seen as one boundary

Comment: What about at $x = -100$?

Comment: yes it would exceed zero x=-100 so it cannot keep going...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fraction is smaller than zero then the denominator is less than zero or the numerator is less or equal to zero (but not both)when the denominator is zero then the numerator is too. So we get $x-5\leq 0$ and $x+10> 0$ so the set is given by $-10< x\leq5$. Try with this to find the answers to your questions.

Comment: I see so the less than zero is part of the range when you plug in a x?

Comment: it is part of your range when $(x-5)/(x+10)\leq 0$

Comment: so then my interior point are all real numbers (-10,5) and my boundary is the point -10 and the point -5 and the set is neither open or closed

Comment: not the point $-5$ but the point $5$

Comment: Indeed the set is not closed or open

Comment: I see thanks for the help